# Magento 2.1 : How to pass variables from PHP to the browser in observer

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript, event-observer, extensions

What I need to do is: When the event `'checkout_cart_save_after'` is dispatched, **get the cart data** (sent in the event dispatch) with an observer.

Then i need to send this data to the **browser (with JS)** and be able to read it **(get products, quantity and all stuff)**.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: which magento version?

Comment: I'm actually using Magento 2!

Comment: Why do you want to use an observer? I think `Google tag manager` is exactly what youre looking for